# python pandas melt on combined columns

Tags: pandas, melt

I have a dataframe like this. i have regular fields till "state" then i will have trailers (3 columns tr1* represents 1 tailer) i want to convert those trailers to rows. I tried melt function but i am able to use only 1 trailer column. kindly look at below example you can understand

```
Name number city       state    tr1num   tr1acct   tr1ct  tr2num  tr2acct   tr2ct   tr3num   tr3acct  tr3ct 
DJ   10     Edison     nj       1001     20345     Dew    1002    20346     Newca.  1003.    20347.   pen 
ND   20     Newark     DE       2001     1985      flor   2002    1986      rodge
```

I am expecting the output like this.

```
Name number city       state    trnum   tracct     trct
DJ   10     Edison     nj       1001     20345     Dew   
DJ   10     Edison     nj       1002     20346     Newca
DJ   10     Edison     nj       1003     20347     pen
ND   20     Newark     DE       2001     1985      flor
ND   20     Newark     DE       2002     1986      rodge
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html?highlight=wide_to_long#pandas-wide-to-long).  However, you will need to do some column renaming first.

```
df = df.set_index(['Name','number','city','state'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)',r'\1\3_\2')
df = df.reset_index()

pd.wide_to_long(df, ['trnum','trct','tracct'], 
                ['Name','number','city','state'], 'Code',sep='_',suffix='\d+')\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('Code',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Name  number    city state   trnum    trct   tracct
0   DJ      10  Edison    nj  1001.0     Dew  20345.0
1   DJ      10  Edison    nj  1002.0  Newca.  20346.0
2   DJ      10  Edison    nj  1003.0     pen  20347.0
3   ND      20  Newark    DE  2001.0    flor   1985.0
4   ND      20  Newark    DE  2002.0   rodge   1986.0
5   ND      20  Newark    DE     NaN     NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have integers in regular columns also eg buw1no. i only gave small example but i have around 50 columns and 500k rows for 1 run

Comment: @NDommeti `pd.wide_to_long` is the method to use, otherwise you end up doing multiple melts and joining the dataframes together.  With pd.wide_to_long, you must get your column headers consistent in a "stub_number" format. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Awesome..will do it..thanks for giving the guidance @Scott Boston. what method should i use if i have to use pyspark.

Comment: @NDommeti I am not familiar enough with pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this by renaming your columns and bit and applying the pandas wide_to_long method. Below is the code which produces your desired output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["DJ", "ND"], "number":[10,20], "city":["Edison", "Newark"], "state":["nj","DE"],
                  "trnum_1":[1001,2001], "tracct_1":[20345,1985], "trct_1":["Dew", "flor"], "trnum_2":[1002,2002],
                  "trct_2":["Newca", "rodge"], "trnum_3":[1003,None], "tracct_3":[20347,None], "trct_3":["pen", None]})

pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['trnum', 'tracct', 'trct'], i='Name', j='dropme', sep='_').reset_index().drop('dropme', axis=1)\
  .sort_values('trnum')
```

## outputs

```
  Name state city number trnum  tracct  trct
0   DJ  nj  Edison  10  1001.0  20345.0 Dew
1   DJ  nj  Edison  10  1002.0  NaN     Newca
2   DJ  nj  Edison  10  1003.0  20347.0 pen
3   ND  DE  Newark  20  2001.0  1985.0  flor
4   ND  DE  Newark  20  2002.0  NaN    rodge
5   ND  DE  Newark  20  NaN     NaN   None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. because i have millions of rows i can't define columns based on actual data. i will research on wide_to_long

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2':[3,4,5], 'col3':[5,6,7], 'tr1':[0,9,8], 'tr2':[0,9,8]})
```

The df:

```
 col1   col2    col3    tr1 tr2
    0   1   3   5   0   0
    1   2   4   6   9   9
    2   3   5   7   8   8
```

subsetting to create 2 df's:

```
tr1_df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'tr1']].rename(index=str, columns={"tr1":"tr"})
tr2_df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'tr2']].rename(index=str, columns={"tr2":"tr"})
res = pd.concat([tr1_df, tr2_df])
```

## result:

```
col1 col2   col3    tr
0   1   3   5   0
1   2   4   6   9
2   3   5   7   8
0   1   3   5   0
1   2   4   6   9
2   3   5   7   8
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor 
import pandas as pd

(df
.pivot_longer(
      index=slice("Name", "state"),
      names_to=(".value", ".value"),
      names_pattern=r"(.+)\d(.+)",
      sort_by_appearance=True)
.dropna()
)

  Name  number    city state   trnum   tracct    trct
0   DJ      10  Edison    nj  1001.0  20345.0     Dew
1   DJ      10  Edison    nj  1002.0  20346.0  Newca.
2   DJ      10  Edison    nj  1003.0  20347.0     pen
3   ND      20  Newark    DE  2001.0   1985.0    flor
4   ND      20  Newark    DE  2002.0   1986.0   rodge
```

The `.value` keeps the part of the column associated with it as header, and since we have multiple `.value`, they are combined into a single word. The `.value` is determined by the groups in the names_pattern, which is a regular expression.

Note that currently the multiple `.value` option is available in dev.